# how to transfer files sequentially in one thread

Tags: java, file, sockets, io, stream

I want to use one thread to transfer multiple files,
on the client side, I just read a file then write them to the outputstream

```
 while ((read = dis.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    passedlen += read;
                    dos.write(buf, 0, read);
 }
```

but it won't stop when the inputsream(dis) has read one file,so all the file s rushed to only one outputstream which writes to one file on my serverside.

so,what can I do to receive my files one bye one through the socket inputstream?

Answer (score 0):

There are protocols for file transfer.

**Solution 1.** You can reinvent your own little protocol : like storing each file length before the file content. Assuming dos is a DataOutputStream :

```
while ( ( file = ... ) != null ) {
  long fileSize = ...
  dos.writeLong(fileSize);

  ... write file data to dos as you did ...

}
```

When you read at the other end, first read the file size, then read fileSize bytes. Repeat until end of stream.

**Alternative solutions**

- Use TAR : it was designed exactly for that purpose. See [JTAR](https://code.google.com/p/jtar/) for java.

Comment: dos.write( buffer.array(), 0, Long.BYTES );
dos means what here?

Comment: @kknight He appears to means an unstated `DataOutputStream,`  but if he has one of those he doesn't need the `ByteBuffer` stuff. The duplicated question has a better answer than this.

Comment: @kknight It means write the content of `buffer.array()` to dos. The size of buffer.array() is `Long.BYTES` bytes. I assume dos is a generic OutputStream on which you can just write bytes.

Comment: OK, the variable name `dos` probably indicates it's a DataOutputStream, so writeLong is more appropriate.

Comment: @Nytux What do you mean 'probably'? It's your code? Isn't it?

Comment: @EJP I'm starting from the code of kknight and his two variables dos and dis that I assumed to be of type OutputStream and InputStream. Anyway, even if they were, the best solution is to encapsulate them into DataOutputStream and DataInputStream. It avoids using ByteBuffers as I did in the first version of my post.

Comment: @EJP thank you,the duplicated question helps.I just tried to use readFully() to work this out,but this method constrains the file length,your answer really works perfectly.